# How to post a button in postMessageToChannel to the slack channel and call a function on click of button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, slack, slack-api

I want to send a button in bot.postMessageToChannel() and want to call a function(handleMessage) on Click of that button.

```
//start handler
bot.on('start', () => {
    const params = {
        icon_emoji: ':information_source:'
    }

    //here i want to post a button to a channel.
    bot.postMessageToChannel(
        'ABC', //channel name
        '*Welcome to AB*...',
         params
    )
})
```

function i want to call,

```
handleMessage = (message) => {
   console.log("hello")
}
```

I have tried the slack API.

[Message Buttons with Node.js](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/intro-to-message-buttons) but it is from the slash commands.

[interactive message button](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-buttons) it is just giving me similar JSON data.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Or better question, what action will the user be doing which will result in your button showing up in the channel?

Comment: @JustinGreywolf I have a slack bot let say **checkbot**  and I want when someone goes to the channel **ABC** and hits the command let say. **@checkbot getinfo** so I want that some button to appear and the button should make some Http calls.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to confirm what you were looking for before I answered.  I did something similar recently - where I would return a button off of a command, mainly so that when the user clicked on the button I would have a `trigger_id` that I could use to send a modal form for them to provide more info.  An example of how I handled this:

First go to the `Event Subscriptions` section of your app settings page, and enable it.  Provide the url that will listen for said events, then you need to select the events that your bot will be listening for.  I subscribed to `app_mention` ( which will fire when your bot is @), and `message.channels`, which will fire on every message sent to the channel your bot is in.

Once you have done that you can subscribe to events...  (by using the slack SDK https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/)

```
slackEvents.on('message', (event, body) => {
    // do something here
    console.log(`Received a message event: user ${event.user} in channel ${event.channel} says ${event.text}`);
  });
```

In my case, once I received that message (I parse through the text to handle multiple commands) I would then use `blocks` to create a message with a button and send it back...

**Payload:**

```
channel: context.channelId,
      text: "",
      blocks: JSON.stringify([
          {
            type: "section",
            text: {
              type: "mrkdwn",
              text: "So, you say you want to create a new task?\n*Great!*\nI just need your permission first, in order to initiate this action.\nPlease click the button below to launch this process, or cancel if you have changed your mind"
            }
          },
          {
            type: "actions",
            block_id: "processAddTask",
            elements: [
              {
                type: "button",
                text: {
                  type: "plain_text",
                  emoji: true,
                  text: "Process"
                },
                style: "primary",
                value: "1"
              },
              {
                type: "button",
                text: {
                  type: "plain_text",
                  emoji: true,
                  text: "Cancel"
                },
                style: "danger",
                value: "0"
              }
            ]
          }
        ])
```

Then send that payload back to channel...

```
const response = await web.chat.postMessage(responseMessage);
```

Once all this was done the user would be presented with a couple of buttons, and when they clicked on the "go" button it will fire another event that you can catch:

```
slackInteractions.action({ callbackId: 'addTaskRequest' }, (payload, respond) => { 
    console.log('payload', payload);
    let triggerId = payload.trigger_id;
    let view = payloads.addTaskModal({ triggerId });

      (async () => {

        try {
            let result = await slackClient.callAPIMethod("views.open", view);
          respond("");
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.code === ErrorCode.PlatformError) {
            respond(error.data);
          } else {
            respond('Well, that was unexpected.');
          }
        }
      })();
});
```